Does JPA criteria allow for writing compound queries like below?
I am trying to write a JPA query because the list of columns (what you see in inner query - like name, color, etc) are dynamic.
This is my query:
select name, color, level, id, type, accountId, viewId from table1 
where (name, color, level) in 
(select name, color, max(level) from table1 where accountId in account_id_list and viewId in view_id_list group by name, color) and accountId in account_id_list and viewId in view_id_list

I tried writing a subquery but it does not have multiselect.
I tried writing it as 2 separate multiselect queries where second query depends on the results of first query. But I could not figure out how to write in query with select columns.
Could someone help write this query?
Also, looks like JPA criteria does not support in query with multiple columns.
